# Akka event message is not dispatch or trigger another event. Always getting triggered first event other events are not getting dispatch

Tags: java, scala, events, akka, message

I am new to Akka, I am trying to trigger or dispatch event message to Akka Actor and I have 3 event message one bye one i am triggering but, why only one first event is getting triggered.

It may be because of : `receive(receiveEvent);` this method call in my `EventProcessActor` constructor.

But after that we are calling other events also but someting i am missing here why its not dispatch to other match events.

I am always getting below output in console:

```
[INFO] [03/18/2017 13:35:53.446]... We received the Events need to process it
```

My Expected output is :

```
[INFO] [03/18/2017 13:35:53.446] ... We received the Events need to process it

[INFO] [03/18/2017 13:35:53.447]...  We are processing Events

[INFO] [03/18/2017 13:35:53.446]... Completed Events processing
```

Above console output I have removed `[default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://default/user/EventProcessing]` with `...`

As I am triggering events like below :

```
procsssEvents.tell(new EventProcessActor.EventActivity(Events.STSRT, Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);
procsssEvents.tell(new EventProcessActor.EventActivity(Events.READING_LINE, Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);
procsssEvents.tell(new ventProcessActor.EventActivity(Events.END_OR,Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);
```

Below is my Acotr class and Message class and pom.xml file.

**AkkaActor:**

```
package com.ebc.biz.akka.event.trigger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import scala.PartialFunction;
import scala.runtime.BoxedUnit;

import akka.actor.AbstractLoggingActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.japi.pf.ReceiveBuilder;

import static com.ebc.biz.akka.event.trigger.EventMessage.Events;

public class EventProcessActor extends AbstractLoggingActor {

    public static class EventActivity {
        final EventMessage startOfEventMessage;

        public EventMessage getStartOfEventMessage() {
            return startOfEventMessage;
        }

        public EventActivity(Events events, Path eventPath) {
            startOfEventMessage = new EventMessage(events, eventPath);
        }

    }

    public static class EventReadingActivity {

        final EventMessage startOfReadingMessage;

        public EventMessage getStartOfReadingMessage() {
            return startOfReadingMessage;
        }

        public EventReadingActivity(Events events, Path eventPath) {
            startOfReadingMessage = new EventMessage(events, eventPath);

        }

    }

    public static class EndOfEventActivity {

        final EventMessage endOfEventMessage;

        public EventMessage getEndOfEventMessage() {
            return endOfEventMessage;
        }

        public EndOfEventActivity(Events events, Path eventPath) {
            endOfEventMessage = new EventMessage(Events.END_OR, eventPath);

        }
    }

    private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receiveEvent;

    private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> startEventsProcessing;

    private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> completeEventProcessing;

    public EventProcessActor() {

        receiveEvent = ReceiveBuilder
                .match(EventActivity.class, this::onStartEventReceive)
                .match(EventReadingActivity.class, this::readEventLine).build();

        startEventsProcessing = ReceiveBuilder
                .match(EventReadingActivity.class, this::readEventLine)
                .match(EndOfEventActivity.class, this::onEndOfEventProcessing)
                .build();

        completeEventProcessing = ReceiveBuilder.match(
                EndOfEventActivity.class, this::onEndOfEventProcessing).build();

        receive(receiveEvent);
    }

    public static Props props() {

        return Props.create(EventProcessActor.class);
    }

    public void onStartEventReceive(EventActivity fileActivity) {
        log().info("We received the Events need to process it");
        getContext().become(startEventsProcessing);
    }

    public void readEventLine(EventReadingActivity fileActivity) {
        log().info("We are processing Events");
        getContext().become(completeEventProcessing);

    }

    public void onEndOfEventProcessing(EndOfEventActivity fileActivity) {
        log().info("Completed Events processing");

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ActorSystem syste = ActorSystemImpl.create();
        final ActorRef procsssEvents = syste.actorOf(EventProcessActor.props(),
                "Event" + "Processing");

        procsssEvents.tell(new EventProcessActor.EventActivity(Events.STSRT,
                Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);
        procsssEvents.tell(new EventProcessActor.EventActivity(
                Events.READING_LINE, Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);
        procsssEvents.tell(new EventProcessActor.EventActivity(Events.END_OR,
                Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);

        System.out.println("Enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();

    }

}
```

**EventMessage**

```
package com.ebc.biz.akka.event.trigger;

import java.nio.file.Path;

public class EventMessage {

    public static enum Events {

        STSRT, READING_LINE, END_OR;

    }

    private final Events readEvents;
    private final Path pathOfEvents;

    public Path getPathOfEvents() {
        return pathOfEvents;
    }

    public Events getReadEvents() {
        return readEvents;
    }

    public EventMessage(Events readEvents, Path pathOfFile) {
        this.readEvents = readEvents;
        this.pathOfEvents = pathOfFile;
    }

}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
 <groupId>com.ebc.biz</groupId>
  <artifactId>akka.event.trigger</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
        <akka.version>2.4.9</akka.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin>3.6.1</maven.compiler.plugin>
        <java.compiler.target>1.8</java.compiler.target>
        <java.compiler.source>1.8</java.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http-experimental_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http-jackson-experimental_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- This will download source so easy to see API and java doc. -->
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Java 8 compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${java.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Why my message are not getting dispatch one to another. I guess i am missing something.

Thanks in advance for any kind of information and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the issue is - you're sending `EventActivity` while actor expects another type per design, so you should update your `main`:

```
    procsssEvents.tell(new EventProcessActor.EventActivity(Events.STSRT, Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);
    procsssEvents.tell(new EventProcessActor.EventReadingActivity(Events.READING_LINE, Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);
    procsssEvents.tell(new EventProcessActor.EndOfEventActivity(Events.END_OR, Paths.get("/")), procsssEvents);
```

Comment: If I am not calling receive(receiveEvent); in the EventProcessActor Constructor than I am getting exception and all message than i am sending from main method are going to "dead letters encountered". 

And only first message are getting fired because i am calling "receive(receiveEvent);" that is first event. 

I tried to put Thread sleep before calling each line of "tell invocation" stil same problem only first event is getting logged or fired.

I tried putting Thread.sleep (2000) in before of each become call  also.

Comment: Right, the issue was somewhere else, I've updated the answer.